# How can I include multiple UITextFields in the Hidekeyboard function given below?

Tags: ios, swift, function, keyboard

I am trying to implement a function that can let decimal pads disappear when the user clicks somewhere else but the keyboard. The issue is that I currently only know this function which to my knowledge only works for 1 textField:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.Alkoholanteil.endEditing(true)
}
```

I could only enter the text field "Referencetime" as you could see. 
Is there a function that allows for the keyboards to disappear when the user is touching else but the keyboard for 4 text fields and not 1?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Please [edit] your question and copy and paste your actual code into your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are much harder to read.

Comment: Call `endEditing` on the view controller's view, not on a specific text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Which will work for all `textField`.

Comment: Thank you very much Richie Rich, you have solved the problem perfectly;)

Comment: Happy to help you and don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.. :)